# Why can't I reference keys in the result of this PHP function?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Why does this code fail

```
function f(){
    return array('k'=>'abc');
}
print_r(f()['k']);
```

and this code work?

```
function f(){
    return array('k'=>'abc');
}
$a = f();
print_r($a['k']);
```

The only difference is the assignment of `f`'s result to  `$a` before trying to access elements of the array. How can I reference the result of `f` directly without the additional assignment?

Comment: I would hit my head, but that would make me lose more braincells than I already have reading about this issue ..

Comment: @user Hooray for language wars on SO!

Comment: @deceze Oh, I toned it down. But it's not a [language] war without an opponent .. I've wasted enough time learning about another "interesting" design decision; although I guess I *did* learn something new :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only available in PHP 5.4. It is known as *array dereferencing*. Prior to 5.4 you have to store the return value and then access the array elements.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

> PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features:
>
> - Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

If you try this on any version below 5.4, you will get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line ...